# How to reduce the gap between a pcolormesh and a colorbar in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset that I want to plot as 4 panels (each a pcolormesh with its associated colorbar). This is the code I'm using to do this, with some mocked up data

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

xs = np.linspace(0.1, 0.2, 100)
ys = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi*0.1, 400)
x_mesh, y_mesh = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)

# mocked up data arrays
A = np.full_like(x_mesh, 1.0)
B = np.full_like(x_mesh, 1.0)
C = np.full_like(x_mesh, 1.0)
D = np.full_like(x_mesh, 1.0)

fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows = 2, ncols = 4, height_ratios = (0.5, 0.5), width_ratios = (0.45, 0.05, 0.45, 0.05))
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])
ax0_cbar = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,2])
ax1_cbar = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,3])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,0])
ax2_cbar = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,2])
ax3_cbar = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,3])
a = ax0.pcolormesh(x_mesh/1.0e-2, y_mesh/1.0e-2, A, \
               shading = 'auto')
cb1 = plt.colorbar(a, cax=ax0_cbar)
cb1.set_label(r"A")
b = ax1.pcolormesh(x_mesh/1.0e-2, y_mesh/1.0e-2, B, \
               shading = 'auto')
cb1 = plt.colorbar(b, cax=ax1_cbar)
cb1.set_label(r"B")
c = ax2.pcolormesh(x_mesh/1.0e-2, y_mesh/1.0e-2, C, \
               shading = 'auto')
cb1 = plt.colorbar(c, cax=ax2_cbar)
cb1.set_label(r"C")
d = ax3.pcolormesh(x_mesh/1.0e-2, y_mesh/1.0e-2, D, \
               shading = 'auto')
cb1 = plt.colorbar(d, cax=ax3_cbar)
cb1.set_label(r"D")
ax0.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax1.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
fig.tight_layout()
```

But when I actually do this, I find that there are really large gaps between the pcolormesh and the colorbars that are really unappealing (picture attached). How can I reduce these? I though I would be able to do it with `fig.tight_layout()` and `width_ratios` in `gridspec`
[image: Figure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't require new axes elements for your colorbars, simply use the ax keyword argument to specify the colorbars for each subplot. The matplotlib documentation shows that using ax will produce a colorbar axis stolen from the parent axes ax (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html). The documentation should be your first port of call, always!

Here I have written a working version of your code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

```
xs = np.linspace(0.1, 0.2, 100)
ys = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi*0.1, 400)
x_mesh, y_mesh = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)

# mocked up data arrays
A = np.full_like(x_mesh, 1.0)
B = np.full_like(x_mesh, 1.0)
C = np.full_like(x_mesh, 1.0)
D = np.full_like(x_mesh, 1.0)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows = 2, ncols = 2, height_ratios = (0.5, 0.5), width_ratios = (0.5, 0.5))
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,0])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,1])
a = ax0.pcolormesh(x_mesh/1.0e-2, y_mesh/1.0e-2, A, \
               shading = 'auto')
cb1 = plt.colorbar(a, ax=ax0)
cb1.set_label(r"A")
b = ax1.pcolormesh(x_mesh/1.0e-2, y_mesh/1.0e-2, B, \
               shading = 'auto')
cb1 = plt.colorbar(b, ax=ax1)
cb1.set_label(r"B")
c = ax2.pcolormesh(x_mesh/1.0e-2, y_mesh/1.0e-2, C, \
               shading = 'auto')
cb1 = plt.colorbar(c, ax=ax2)
cb1.set_label(r"C")
d = ax3.pcolormesh(x_mesh/1.0e-2, y_mesh/1.0e-2, D, \
               shading = 'auto')
cb1 = plt.colorbar(d, ax=ax3)
cb1.set_label(r"D")
ax0.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax1.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Happy coding

Comment: Please don't try to be overly pedantic. There exist situations where creating a grid layout including the colorbars makes perfect sense, and the fact that `fig.tight_layout()` doesn't work here as expected, is not due to OP's ignoring to read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The approach above is correct.  It can break down if you have equal aspect axes, for which you can now use `layout='compressed'` for simple cases to remove white space:

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, layout='compressed', figsize=(6, 3))
for ax in axs.flat:
    pc = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.randn(10, 10))
    ax.set_aspect(1)
    fig.colorbar(pc, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

See also: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/colorbar_placement.html